# automatically post form when leaving page

Tags: javascript

This is a plain javascript question.

I have a page C in which sits a textarea T.
T's content gets added to by clicks on various buttons on C (essentially T accumulates the list of times at which the buttons were clicked).

There is also a button to submit the contents of T by a post request to a server (T being surrounded by a form element).

When the user forgets to click the submit button and closes the page's window, I want the posting of T's contents to happen anyway, just as if the user had clicked the submit button before closing the window.

I know I can intercept the page closing and prompt the user to do the submit, but that is NOT what I want.

It seems to be impossible to submit the form containing T from inside a function that is called by onbeforeunload.

Thanks for any tip.

Comment: *"I know I can intercept the page closing and prompt the user to do the submit, but that is NOT what I want."* It should be. That's the right thing to do. That or track the changes as they're made, via ajax, rather than waiting for a "submit".

Answer (score 4):

This is simply not possible : this is a security measure designed to ensure a site can't prevent a user instantly leaving a page if he wants to.

The best you can do is posting your form using ajax each time a field is changed.

Comment: Thanks.  I was afraid of that.  The whole thing is running on my laptop, not connected to the net.
I'm just tracking my own clicks, but often forget to save the trace.  So I'll just have to do tracking as suggested.
However, do not tell me what I _should_ be doing or what is _right to do_

Answer (score 0):

I've used this code in part of my application - it doesn't capture any text though but you could give it a try.

```
window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;

function confirmExit(){

    data = $("#data").val();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'complete.php?data=' + data
    });

}
```

Comment: Yes - it's worked on IE8+, FF, Chrome and Safari from my tests